# What is this "filled circle cut into two pieces" symbol on a schematic diagram?

Tags: schematics, symbol

I'm confused as to whether or not this symbol has any significance, and if so what it means. If anyone could help me figure out its meaning, I would appreciate it.

Close-up of the symbol:
[image: close-up of specific symbol]

---

More of the schematic:
[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: It's a piece of track meant as a jumper you can close with a blot of solder.

Comment: Note for future readers: Almost identical is [this question](/questions/444602), except *there* the solder jumper is joined by default, and *here* the symbol suggests the jumper is open by default - hence arguably not quite a duplicate (?). Also see [here](/questions/377159) for another solder jumper symbol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should find two pads on the PCB shaped rather like those of the drawing with a small gap between them. If you want to power the SBC from the 5 V supply you bridge them out with solder.

Comment: Also, the pads on the PCB are generally shaped in this way (with the far ends rounded) to encourage the solder bridge to form. With square ends it can be very hard to make the solder bridge the gap.